# Customising nutch

Tags: java, nutch

I am using cygwin to run nutch with the command

```
bin/nutch crawl urls -dir crawl -depth 3 -topN 50
```

Now, I am trying to make changes to crawl.java, but when I run again, the changes are not getting reflected in the output. Infact, even if main parts of the code are REMOVED, the command runs without errors and produces the same output.

How to make the changes in code get reflected in the output? I am a beginner, so kindly help out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, for beginners :

Download apache ant and install it in the home folder of `cygwin` (if that's what you are using to run nutch)

Once you make changes to your code, execute the following commands in `cygwin`, after `cd-ing` to the project directory.

1) `ant clean`

2) `ant`

This will clean and build the project. Now run it, the changes in your code will be reflected.

Answer (score 0):

copy content of "out" folder into "build" folder!

Comment: I don't seem to find any out folder or build folder in my nutch folder. Where should it be exactly? I only have a build.xml file. Kindly clarify. :)

Comment: would you mind to give me a list of folders in your nutch project?